# Lake Tahoe kayaking conditions

Tags: kayaks, california

My wife and I would like to take my 7 year old son kayaking this summer. Was thinking about a circumnavigation of [Lake Tahoe](http://laketahoewatertrail.org/explore-water-trail/). It looks like there are plenty of put ins and take outs. I am curious how rough are the waters and how difficult are the landings/launches? Is there anything else unique to paddling on Lake Tahoe that we need to be aware of?

Comment: Landing and launching is a breeze almost everywhere on the lake. 

There is a boating only campground in Emerald Bay you should check out.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a possibility of strong winds,

> Lake Tahoe is also known for its vibrant blue skies, its sparkling **cold waters**, and its **hazardous wind conditions**, especially on the eastern side of the lake.

[Source](http://www.paddlingcalifornia.com/article_Kayaking_Lake_Tahoe.html)

and it may take a lot of padding in some places to make it to the next legal put in/take out

> Paddling completely around Lake Tahoe is popular, but **involves challenging conditions and should be planned carefully.** The entire trip is approximately 72 miles and no legal overnight camping is allowed between the Lake Forest Campground at Pomin Park on the northwest shore and Zephyr Cove Resort on the southeast shore – a **paddle distance of approximately 35 miles**.

[Source](http://www.sierranevadageotourism.org/content/lake-tahoe-water-trail/sieecae3ff96768a7644)

Beyond that, it looks like this [site](http://laketahoewatertrail.org/) would have all of the information you would need.

Comment: The lake is quite cold until August. Many swim in the summer but it is still dangerous.